# How to prove this problem related to the Sequences of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

For $n=1,2,3,\dotsb,$ let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function defined by 
$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}$ for any $x\in\mathbb R.$ Find a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i\rightarrow f$ pointwise on $\mathbb R.$ And show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i$ does not converge to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think of $x$ as a fixed number then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) = x^2 \cdot\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)^{n-1}}.
\end{align}
Now use the geometric series formula.

Comment: What about the uniform convergent part? I see that this series above converges to $1+x^2$.

Comment: @s1mple well, what have you tried? Start by writing down the definitions of uniform convergence. Try to see why it is/isn't satisfied

Comment: Thank you for your hint and I get $f(x)=1+x^2$ easily but I do feel confused about the uniform part, is $x=0$ the key?

Comment: Since if $x=0,$ then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n=0$ while $f(x)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

What you want to see is if $|S_n(x)-f(x)| \to 0$ uniformly where $(S_n)$ is the partial sum sequence of the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ and $f(x)=1+x^{2}$. You can see that $|S_N(x)-f(x)| =\frac  1 {(1+x^{2})^{N-1}}$ for $x >0$. To see that this does not tend to $0$ uniformly put $x =\frac  1 {\sqrt N}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I get that $f(x)=1+x^2$, but it is hard to get $|S_n(x)-f(x)| =\frac 1 {(1+x^{2})^{N-1}}.$

Comment: Use the formula $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} r^{k}=\frac {r-r^{n+1}} {1-r}$ for $0 \leq r <1$.

Comment: If we put $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ and $N\to\infty$, which implies that we only need to concern that whether $x=0$ or not?

Comment: If we define that $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1+x^2 &x\ne 0 \\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$, then this function is what it requied instead of $f(x)=1+x^2$?

Comment: Yes, $f(0)=0$ but that does not change my answer. The sup of $|S_n(x)-f(x)|$ over all $x$ is $\geq |S_N(\frac  1 {\sqrt N}-f(\frac  1 {\sqrt N})|$ which does not tend to $0$.